# Given the value of a dictionary field, how can I find a dictionary in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

Based on a list of fastfoods (list of dictionaries), for each fastfood (each dictionary), I'm trying to 1) extract the competitor's name and then 2) use that competitor's name to retrieve its shortname.

Currently my solution really doesn't make sense and I have a feeling it might be recursive? I'm really having an issue conceptualizing this.

```
fastfoods = [{'id': 30, 'name': 'McDonalds', 'shortname': 'MC', 'competitor': 'BurgerKing'}, {'id': 47, 'name': 'BurgerKing', 'shortname': 'BK', 'competitor': None}]

for fastfood in fastfoods:
    competitor_name = fastfood.get('competitor')
    short_name = fastfood.get('shortname')

    for fastfood in fastfoods:
        if competitor_name == short_name:
            print(fastfood.get('shortname')
```

Here's a visualization of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

In this limited example I have (real example has thousands of dictionaries, but I'm using 2 just for the example.

So here, I loop over the dictionaries, I reach the first dictionary, I extract the competitor's name ('BurgerKing'). At this point, I want to search for 'BurgerKing' as a 'name' field (not as a competitor field). Once that's found, I access that dictionary where the 'name' field == 'BurgerKing' and extract the shortname ('BK').

Comment: You have a loop `for fastfood in fastfoods:` inside the loop `for fastfood in fastfoods:`. That's confusing and error-prone. Use different variable names. For instance, use `for potential_competitor in fastfoods:` for the inner loop. And then, `if competitor_name == short_name:` should be `if competitor_name == potential_competitor.get('name'):`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```py
byName = {dct['name']:dct for dct in fastfoods}
for fastfood in fastfoods:
    if 'competitor' in fastfood and fastfood['competitor'] is not None:
        competitor = byName[fastfood['competitor']]
        if 'shortname' in competitor:
            print(competitor['shortname'])
        else:
            print(f"competitor {fastfood['competitor']} has no shortname")
```

Explanation:

- create `byName`, a dictionary that indexes dicts in `fastfoods` by their `name` entry
- iterate over all dicts in `fastfoods`
- if a given dict has a `competitor` entry and it's non-null, look up the dict for that `competitor` by name in `byName` and if it has a `shortname` entry print it
- otherwise print a message indicating there is no `shortname` entry for the `competitor` (you can do something different in this case if you like).

Answer (score 0):

I would first construct a dictionary that maps a name to its shortened version, and then use it. This would be way faster than looking for the competitor in the list over and over again.

```py
fastfoods = [{'id': 30, 'name': 'McDonalds', 'shortname': 'MC', 'competitor': 'BurgerKing'}, {'id': 47, 'name': 'BurgerKing', 'shortname': 'BK', 'competitor': None}]

name_to_short = {dct['name']: dct['shortname'] for dct in fastfoods}

for dct in fastfoods:
    print(f"The competitor of {dct['name']} is: {name_to_short.get(dct['competitor'], 'None')}")

# The competitor of McDonalds is: BK
# The competitor of BurgerKing is: None
```